# Webpack: How to exclude entry file itself?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm new to Webpack and am looking for an option to exclude my single entry from the bundling.

So my `webpack.config.js` right now looks simply like this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './all.js',
    output: {
        path: 'dist',
        filename: 'all.bundle.js'
    }
};
```

`all.js` is already a bundle created by the TypeScript transpiler, but without the third-party dependencies. I prefer to have the rest of the bundle - the third party dependencies - be bundled separately by Webpack as then the TypeScript is the only build I will have to make after the vast majorities of changes during development.

So far, calling `webpack` correctly builds a bundle of all the dependencies, but it includes the entry.

So is there a way to exclude the entry?

Answer (score 0):

I am confused because you want to exclude the entry point. I think you need to have separate the libraries and  the application. So you create two entry points one for the vendors and one application so that it creates two bundles. Or you add your libraries as externals and add then globally on browser.

I think you want to try the [common chunk plugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html):

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
      app: 'app.js',
      all: './all.js',// This could be an array ['jquery', ...]
},
        output: {
            path: 'dist',
            filename: 'all.bundle.js'
        },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("all", "all.bundle.js")
      ]
        };
```

Other possibility is to add the libraries as [externals](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html) and add then globally before your application script.

```
module.exports = {
    entry: 'app.js',
        output: {
            path: 'dist',
            filename: 'all.bundle.js'
        },
externals: {
  all: 'all.js'
        };
```

Comment: That would exclude jquery. I want to exclude the entry - `all.js` in my case.

Comment: No - as I said, I'm really new to this. I'll look into it.

Comment: Hmm, neither the `CommonsChunkPlugin` nor the `externals` approach had any effect on the output I'm seeing yet. In the case of `CommonsChunkPlugin` I even somewhat doubt it should work: The docs say it's supposed to figure out the common part of multiple entries - I have just one entry.

Comment: yeah, i tried to explain that you might need to create a few entries, i think is the easier solution